# Fixed space of absolutely Frobenius

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, galois-groups, frobenius-map

Let $A$ be an affine space over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$, $F$ be the absolutely Frobenius. Let $B$ be an $F-$ invariant affine subspace contained in $A$, $B^F$ be the fixed points of $F$ in $B$.

My question: $dim_{\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q}(B)$=$dim_{\mathbb{F}_q}(B^F)$?

Comment: This is true, and it follows from the Grothendieck--Lefschetz trace formula. I believe there is a proof somewhere in Chap-10 of Digne--Michel's book Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type (1st ed.).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Let me see...

Comment: Do you mean relative Frobenius? Any subspace is invariant under absolute Frobenius...

Comment: I wonder that if $B$ is replaced by any other $F-$ invarinant closed sub variety, is there a similar conclusion?

Comment: Maybe I have abused the notation

Comment: Dear Damian:Here the Frobenius I mean is,for point$(x,y,z..)\in A$,$F((x,y,z...))=(x^q,y^q,z^q...)$ @Damian Rössler

Comment: I think the OP intends to ask the following question (and my comment above is for this one): If $A$ is an $n$-dim affine space over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$, then its number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points with respect to any $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational structure is $q^n$.

Comment: Yes, I mean this one. Thanks

Comment: OK so you mean the relative Frobenius.